# simulate keyboard keys in app inventor or thunkable or kodular like app building websites

Tags: java, kotlin, app-inventor

i want to somehow simulate ctrl+a and ctrl+c in my app inventor app, but how do i do so, i want to copy the whole elements(not the source code, because the web page only has elements and source codes shows nothing) of a web viewer using this method for checking a particular text/string in a web-page. bottom line is i want to simulate a keypress without pressing the key in my app.

tried activity starter but there are so less examples of it.

app-inventor is based on blocks but still some extensions might help

i tried everything and now i'm out of any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to copy a web page without pressing any key in your app then try this one.

Use Web component with webView
drag and drop web1.GotText block

with this block, you can easily get response Content and store it in a variable
and do want to do with it.

if you didn't understand what I want to say then let me know in the comment I will upload screenshots next time.